# AngularJS create controller only one time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I investigated how i can create controller only one time, but i did not found any really good solutions.

A have found some *workarounds* only:

1. create controller list in $rootScope and add here created controllers
2. create masterController and in its scope apply solution to save all created controllers in collection in masterControllerScope

So if my template loads, i have to use *special myService* to agregate controllers, also service have to do checks. If controller was already created - old one should be loaded, not new one, other way add just created to controller collection.

Algorithm seems simple, but ugly for using with angular. I hope i very weak with angular and this is reason why i did not find better solution.

***Can you please suggest better idea or solution!?***  Possible I need redesign something or service which i need is already implemented in base library...

**Adding more clarification:**

```
ng-app=singleApplication
|-ng-view
```

SingleApplication has *ng-route* to manage templates for *ng-view*. Each template has an *unique controller*. Every time if different with current view applies, i see controller creation. But I need do not ask server for data, if template was loaded once. I need to show template with old data, tables, controls, but i can not if controller is creating every time. All data loaded in *controller-scope* (*this*), all keys are unique in *controller-scope*, but i do not have good guarantee if i save data to *$scope* or *$rootScope*.

Comment: are you trying to create one controller and use it across modules right?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  There's probably more straightforward ways to do what you want with angular

Comment: no, I have only one module and few controllers (one controller per template), if i use filter in template or navigated to n-page in table in the controller all data resets with extra server request. So I think I need ability to create some controllers only one time.

Comment: I believe that angular saves created controllers somewhere, i just have to know it and how to reuse already created controllers managed by angular.

Comment: What's the purpose of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Sergii, if there is only one module, everything resides in that module - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/bZoVVG

Comment: if you dont want the data to reset or share between controllers you can using sharing services or lesser popular option of `$rootScope`

Comment: Dear helpers! i have added some details to question, sorry for appeared misunderstanding.

Comment: @NagaSaiA thank you for your good example it demonstrates how to share data between controllers using shared _scope_.

Comment: @maddog thank you for suggestion, i thought about it, but i also thought controllers data which should not be shared with other controllers have to be put in _this controller_

**My mistake was in idea to use same controller but I need only same data, and customized properties!**

Comment: @Sergii, if my post is helpful, please mark it as answered :)

Comment: @NagaSaiA, **i have voted for your answer**. I think its good mark for your answer, because i believe there is can be more better solution and i waiting for it.

Comment: @NagaSaiA also please pay attention please, Your answer does not answer to general topic question. It provides advise to use different solution way

Answer (score 2):

If all controllers are created under one module, then we can controller with that module

Please find the example below

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);


app.controller('TextController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.text = {
        message: 'Welcome!!'
    };
});

app.controller('ItemController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [{
        title: 'Pencil',
        quantity: 8,
        price: 4.2
    }, {
        title: 'Pen',
        quantity: 2,
        price: 5.2
    }, {
        title: 'Watch',
        quantity: 3,
        price: 10.2
    }];
});
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/bZoVVG